# map reduce word count example

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to run a simple example of word count with map reduce. but I have this problem and have no idea how to solve it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTrackerInstrumentation.create(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTrackerInstrumentation; @5: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/lib/DefaultMetricsSystem' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/MetricsSystem'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @5
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker', 'org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker', 'org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf', 'org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/lib/DefaultMetricsSystem' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2b b200 03b8 0004 b0
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem - did you figure it out?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and it got solved by removing some unneeded references in Maven (hadoop-common and hadoop-hdfs).
I'm using hadoop 2.2.0 from Windows, connecting to Linux hadoop single-node cluster.

Comment: Or just reordering Maven dependencies.
Or if you don't use Maven, then try to remove/reorder your .classpath libraries

Comment: How should I re-order it to get this error resolved?

Comment: I suggest you just first remove unneeded references and then reorder. Also note that the hadoop-core should not be used in new versions. My pom says (in this order): hadoop-common, hadoop-mapreduce-client-core, hadoop-hdfs (depending on what you need)

Comment: I had the same issue. In my case, it was necessary to put `hadoop-core` before `hadoop-common` in the dependencies of the `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

the below order for dependencies solved the problem for me.

```
hadoop-core 1.2.1
hadoop-common 2.6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The below dependencies worked for me

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>     

    </dependencies>
```